# How do I avoid having to manually source ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc to get "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to work?

Tags: command-line, bashrc, 23.10, .profile

I realized that I need to manually `source ~/.bashrc` file or to manually `source .profile` file to make the settings specified in .bashrc file effective. These are some additions to complete `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/wx
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/wx/3.3.0

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/raphy/wxWidgets
```

Important to note that I'm having this issue of not-permanent settings of `.bashrc` only for the `wxWidgets` library, for which I added the last four lines.

I commented the `wx` library path in `.bashrc` and added these lines in
`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf` and ran `sudo ldconfig`:

```
raphy@raohy:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo ldconfig
raphy@raohy:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ cat wx.conf 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/wx
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/wx/3.3.0
```

But the problem persists.

What do I have to do to avoid to manually do `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150743/discussion-on-question-by-raphael10-ubuntu-23-10-what-do-i-have-to-do-to-avoid); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Side note (not sure if this was pointed out already): If your `.bashrc` contains `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/raphy/wxWidgets` as the last line, all the other `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` lines are meaningless - its final value will be just `/home/raphy/wxWidgets`. So if that's the path that actually works for you, then that's what you should be adding to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/whatever`

Comment: @muru I tried to put in `/etc.ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf` only `/home/raphy/wxWidgets` -> `sudo ldconfig` -> `sudo reboot`. But, again, executing minimal app in the very first terminal after rebooting , the app is without menubar and without menu items, while if I open a second terminal and execute the minimal app there, it opens up correctly, with its menubar and its menu items. And if I execute the app clicking its icon, again, it opens up without its menubar and without its menu items

Comment: In that case I recommend trying to reduce your changes on the default config to absolute _minimum_ needed to get things working. Once we have that, we can identify exactly what needs to go where.

Comment: @muru at the moment in `.bashrc` there is no line about `wxWidgets`, while  `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf` contains only this line: `/home/raphy/wxWidgets`. And with this setting this is the behaviour: executing the minimal app through clicking its icon, or executing it via command-line in the very first terminal after reboot, shows up an incomplete app, without its menubar and its menu items; while if I open a second terminal and execute the minimal app in it, it opens correctly, with all its menubar and its menu items

Comment: "at the moment in .bashrc there is no line about wxWidgets" and no other lines about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all?

Comment: @muru there were actually other lines with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.bashrc`. I `commented them all` -> `source ~/.bashrc` -> in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` folder : `sudo ldconfig` -> `sudo reboot` . But the problem persists: executing the minimal app through clickin its icon, or via command-line in the very first terminal after reboot, shows up an incomplete app without its menubar and its menu items. If I open a second terminal, and execute the minimal app via command-line within this second terminal, it opens correctly, with all its menubar and its menu items

Comment: Yes, yes, we all get it. You don't need to repeat the "first time this, second time this" in every comment. Add _useful_ information only please. And as I said: reduce your config changes to the absolute minimum required first. What happens if you undo _all_ your changes and use the default files? What happens if you set just a single path for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and nothing else? What happens if you remove that config and update `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/whatever` with that path? (And so on)

Comment: @muru I updated my post above with all the trials you suggested to do (Update 1). But the problem persists.

Comment: So the result is basically that all this talk of library paths and so on is a red herring that has nothing to do with your actual problem since the problem presents in exactly the same way with the original Ubuntu configuration and all your LD configuration changes. None of the changes you're making or made in the past had any _real_ effect. So now the thing to do is actually debug this app to see what's going on. But that's a question for [so], where you should post the minimal code needed to reproduce this.

Comment: @muru I already made two posts in `wxWidgets` Forum: 1) https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=50976 . 2) https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=50981 . In the first post I just wrote that according to a commenter here may be it's an issue related to `wxWidgets`.  And already wrote in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778357/the-hello-world-example-appears-with-no-menubar-and-no-menu-items?noredirect=1#comment137120865_77778357

Comment: Excellent! In that case we can clean up this post to only focus on the original question: making changes to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` permanent. The rest of it is now basically extra debugging info for the other posts and doesn't belong here.

Comment: Probably delete the cached links file `sudo rm /etc/ld.so.cache` and then run `sudo ldconfig` to regenerate it and see if that works ... I would consider the final behavior as a minor issue probably resulting from you defining things too many times in many different ways and that unfortunately not something that we can guess or as @muru suggests, it might be inconclusive to Ubuntu.

Comment: I removed `ld.so.cache` and regenerated the cache with `sudo ldconfig` and rebooted. But the problem persists. But I'm pretty sure now, after so many step-by-step trials with Ubuntu configuration, that is an issue of the "Hello World" minimum example delivered within the `wxWidgets` official folder: I executed, by clicking on it, an example app found in another repo, and it works perfectly with all its Menu Toolbad and Menu Items. I wrote also in `wx-users` google group describing what I've found.Thanks again to both of you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those library paths probably should go in a configuration file under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` ... So create a file e.g. `mylibs.conf` under that directory and add those paths one path per line (*no colons, no quotes, no `export` and no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` ... just bare paths*) like:

```
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/wx
/usr/local/lib/wx/3.3.0
```

... and save the file.

**Notice** those should be paths to the directories containing the library files and **not** to the library files themselves.

Afterwords,run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

... and reboot.

... and remove them from `~/bashrc` for good practice and not to have things defined in so many places that you can't track them later on.

Comment: I re-installed the wxWidgets library to check the correct path (I updated my post above with the GistGitHub containing the complete log of the `sudo make install` process. It seems that the main folder containing the library is just `/usr/local/lib`. So I updated `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/wx.conf` accordingly, and executed `sudo ldconfig`. After rebooting I noticed that I do not need to `source ~/.bashrc` anymore, even if the correct output of `./minimum` can be seen on the second screen opened, not on the first one (I do not understand why this happens). Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Raphael10 You are welcome ... BTW if it's only `/usr/local/lib`, then it might most probably be already there in some config file like e.g. in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` and all you need to do in that case is to run `sudo ldconfig` after installation to create links and caches for the newly added libraries in that directory.

Comment: I've done `sudo ldconfig` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`
where `wx.conf` contains only this line:

    `/usr/local/lib`

and I rebooted.

Oddly it happens something I do not understand:
If I execute the file, the minimal app opens without any Menubar and with no Menu Items (left screenshot: I updated my post above), while if I execute it through the command-line, it correctly shows up Menubar and Menu Items (right screenshot): `raphy@raohy:~$ ./minimal`